# Android Devise is offline in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, offline

I try these before :

> 1.Restart adb by issuing 'adb kill-server' followed by 'adb start-server' at a           cmd prompt
>
> 2.Disable and re-enable USB debugging on the phone.
>
> 3.Rebooting the phone if it still doesn't work.

1.Navigate to where .android is stored

2.open .android and delete file named as adbkey and adbkey.pub

3.Start ADB then typeadb kill serverand adb start server

> Go to tools/enable adb integration and uncheck it. now check it and
>   run again. Next time, android studio will restart adb and it may find
>   your device

1.Disconnect the USB connection (or turn off the device's Wi-Fi if you're connected over Wi-Fi).
2.Close Eclipse/other IDE.

3.Check your running programs for adb.exe (Task Manager in Windows). If it's running, terminate it.

4.Restart your Android device.

5.After your device restarts, connect it via USB and run 'adb devices'. This should start the ADB daemon. And you should see your device online again

> I have this problem with many device. only with LG p768 it
>   works.corresponding driver is installed. but still my problem is
>   unsolved. any other approach?

Comment: Change USB cable and check it. Because I am facing same issue with my one phone. I changed USB cable and It's working fine.

Comment: Its works fine if you just kill server and start a new server using cmd.